# Как вставить переменную с бинарной операцией между чисел?

Tags: javascript

```
this.arrMethods = [{
    met: '+',
    getResult(str) {
      return +str[0] this.met +str[1];
    },
}];
```

Это кусок кода, где +str[0] равен 3, а str[1] равен 5, нужно сделать так, чтобы между ним был плюс из this.met, но как это реализовать, я не понимаю.. Мне нужно, чтобы обязательно бинарным вычислением было то, что находится в met, так что просто поставить + не вариант.

Comment: ничего не понятно)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто для галочки покажу вариант без `eval`, но тут придется и ваш код немного поправить

```
const commands = {
  '+': (a, b) => a + b,
  '-': (a, b) => a - b
}


this.arrMethods = [{
    met: '+',
    getResult(str) {
      // сюда для подстраховки добавить проверку, что commands[this.met] существует
      return commands[this.met](+str[0], +str[1]);
    },
}];
```

`commands` хранит список команд и их реализацию, через `commands[this.met]` как раз таки выбираем нужную команду и вызываем ее

Comment: Спасибо большое, решение отличное, но не со всем подходит к моему коду) Нужно переписывать условия разные

Answer (score 0):

> так что просто поставить + не вариант.

Как раз это единственный и верный вариант. Можно еще через `eval` сделать, но за это вас быстро сожгут на костре.

Изучите паттерн проектирования "комманда" и "простая фабрика" это поможет реализовать задуманное. Второе - для выбора класса реализации, а первый паттерн - для реализации нужной операции. Может быть вместо "команда" можно использовать "стратегия", где например стратегия `SumStrategy` в методе `handle(a, b)`  будет возвращать `a + b`

---

Если без паттернов, то решается всё через `switch/case`

Comment: Я понял лишь немногое из того, что вы написали. Какой-то уже, видимо, высший уровень пилотажа. Я пока не готов к такому, только начинающий)

Comment: Самое простое для вас - сделать через switch/case. Но придётся так или иначе вручника прописать варианты операций для каждого необходимого знака

Comment: Да, я как раз догнал как это сделать) Наглядный пример привели на другом сайте. Так или иначе, оказалось лучшим решением, чтоб не ковыряться в коде.